# Регулярные выражения asp.net core / angular

Tags: asp.net-core, angular

Подскажите, пожалуйста - следующая стоит задача -  заполнение поля «номенклатурный код» используя регулярные выражения (шаблон «XXX-111111»). Подскажите, как это реализовать и лучше на asp.net core либо angular. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Вот так можно

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
...
string pattern = @"\[A-Z]{3}-\d{6}";
string input = "XXX-111111";
      Match m = Regex.Match(input, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
      if (m.Success)
         Console.WriteLine("Found ");
   }
```